# Wp-cron.php firing too many times , even disabled in wordpress wp-config.php,

Tags: plugins

I am facing issue with too may request from wp-cron.php, While i have already disabled it in wp-config.php , Also added it above below line in wp-config.php

```
define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', true );
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
```

Along with it disable alternate cron as well still it's firing too many times

Comment: What do you mean by "firing too many times"?

Comment: Too many hits, While i have disabled cron.php , every minutes wp-cron.php?doing_cron is calling

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is due to core WordPress and not some plugin or theme interfering?

Comment: yes i am sure, I have already deleted all plugins and placed die on theme index file